# jQuery counting highest number of children in parents

Tags: jquery, html

I'd appreciate help on the following problem:
Let's say I have a number of `ul` elements on a page, each with a number of `li` children, e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

What would be the best way to find the *highest number of children* across all ul parents (In the example above, it should return **3**)?

Many thanks,
Ch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need this:

```
var high = Math.max.apply(null, $('ul').map(function () {
    return $(this).children().length;
}).get());
alert(high);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ctm716zu/)

Comment: you are missing a parentheses `.get());`

Comment: @semisemiotic glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check how many `li` elements `ul` containing by checking `length`

Try [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bsg3wpoh/2/)

```
var highest='0';
$('ul').each(function(){
  var elem=$(this).find('li').length; 
  if(elem >= highest)
     highest=elem;
});

alert("Highest no. of li elements is "+highest);
```